# Declaring CSS style inside Javascript for D3 graph

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, d3.js

So I know how to use CSS with my D3 force layout graph but I am trying to put this graph on WordPress using the wp-D3 plugin and it is not compatible with CSS. I tried to include a link to a CSS file in WordPress but that did not work either. So my next step is to try and declare CSS inside my JavaScript but I am not sure how.

```
      var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
       .data(graph.links)
       .enter().append("line")
       .attr("class", "link")
       .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
       return Math.sqrt(d.value);
   });
```

The`svg.selectAll(".link")` refers to the CSS that I used to have but took out. Without it in the CSS, no links appear on the force layout graph.

Here is a link to a fiddle with the graph:

http://jsfiddle.net/ohiobucks23/jH28Z/

Comment: To see the links, I think you need to set the stroke color, too:            `.style("stroke", "#000")`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Okay...that was a lot easier than I thought. That is exactly what I am asking and that works. I was trying to do `.style("fill", "red")` instead of stroke. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help =) I added an answer so it's clear your question was answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a stroke color to the links, e.g.

```
.style("stroke", "#000")
```